# Combining multiple preg_replace into one

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to remove every `class="imgbrd lazy"` and **after that** delete any `scr=""` and **after that** change `data-original` to `scr`

Individually it looks like this

```
$input = preg_replace('#class="imgbrd lazy"#s', '' ,$input);
$input = preg_replace('#src=".*?"#s', '' ,$input); 
$input = preg_replace('#data-original=#s', 'src=' ,$input);
```

Suppose the $input is this

`<img class="imgbrd lazy" src="/something/iage.png" data-original="/albums/uploadedpics/small1/017246.jpg" border="0">`

The issue is that `scr` get deleted even if `"imgbrd lazy"` isn't found

Comment: @vks i added the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class="imgbrd lazy"([\s\S]*?)src=".*?"
```

Use this.Replace by `$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/40

Comment: it works but if there are any attribute between the `class="imgbrd lazy"` and `scr` , it delete that as well

Comment: @user2650277 no it will not be deleted.See demo.https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/51 Replace by `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
class="imgbrd lazy"\s+src=".*?"\s+data-original=
```

Use the baove regex and then replace the matched charcaters with `src=`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/42)